# React Hook setState not set on promise

Tags: react-native, variables, es6-promise, react-hooks, contentful

I'm using the Contentful CMS JS SDK and the code below does not update my React Hook state. It's more of a promises combined with react hooks combined with React render issue - I believe. I understand that the promise sets the hook value when it is resolved at a later time, but by that time my component already rendered with the initial data (empty string), so if this is the case, how can I make my component re-render when the react hook state is set with the correct value from the promise, so that my Button displays it.
Any help appreciated. Thanks

Problem lies within here.

```
...
import client from 'contentful'
  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  client.getEntry(data.fields.store.sys.id)
    .then(entry => setName(entry.fields.name))
    .catch(console.error)

  console.log('STORE URL', name) // name is not set
...
<Button title={name} /> // name still not set
....
```

Comment: it re-renders automatically, if it's empty string then the most likely cause is that the Promise never resolved (and the code inside `then` never executed) - you can add a console log there to check

Comment: ..second most likely that `entry.fields.name` is also an empty string

Comment: tip: make `.then(entry => console.log("entered then", entry) || setName(entry.fields.name))` so you can keep the one liner arrow function

Comment: the console.log works, and output the right value, so that must mean the state of the name (setName hook) is set too with the right value. But my Button does not receive the name, other than its initial value of an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and it seems to work for me. :)

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hooks-demo-e4wgo

I think you should use `useEffect` though as described [in this article](https://reactgo.com/ajax-requests-fetch-data-using-react-hooks/).